# Parse.com validating user credentials every launch

Tags: parse-platform

On apps like twitter and snapchat, if you changed the password from the web, it wouldn’t allow you to get into the app without re-authenticating with the new password. When changing your password with Parse Open Source Framework, does it implement this functionality automatically on mobile or would the developer need to implement it themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it by yourself. Check the following tutorial, section Handling an Invalidated Session:
https://parse.com/tutorials/integrating-facebook-in-android